# How to update a button's text in each listview's item ?(Android)

Tags: android, listview

I want to create a listview and it's item like this:
I can not post images, i am sorry . This is the image :

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-tQ0Uh8-YhkE/U6Qsz9Y0FAI/AAAAAAAADPc/dDerCtq_6jQ/w487-h865-no/Screenshot_2014-06-20-20-40-07.png

click the download button it will download the file ,and what i want to do is ,when the download completed , it want to set the button's text to "Use It".
Please help , i have no idea to do that.
This is my Adapter :

```
class SaveListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<SaveModel> savesList;
    private Context context;

    public SaveListAdapter(Context context) {

        this.context = context;
    }

    public void addItem(SaveModel model) {
        if (null != savesList && !savesList.contains(model)) {
            this.savesList.add(savesList.size(), model);
        } else if (null == savesList) {
            this.savesList = new ArrayList<SaveModel>();
            this.savesList.add(model);
        }
    }

    public void addItems(List<SaveModel> modelList) {
        if (null != savesList) {
            Iterator<SaveModel> listIterator = modelList.iterator();
            while (listIterator.hasNext()) {
                SaveModel model = listIterator.next();
                addItem(model);
            }
        } else {
            this.savesList = modelList;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (null != savesList) {
            return savesList.size();
        } else
            return 0;
    }

    public void removeAllItems() {
        if (null != this.savesList) {
            this.savesList.clear();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public SaveModel getItem(int position) {
        if (null != savesList)
            return savesList.get(position);
        else
            return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        final SaveModel model = savesList.get(position);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (null == convertView) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                    R.layout.item_card, null);
            viewHolder.gamePicIMG = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_card_save_pic_Image);
            viewHolder.saveTitleTV = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_card_save_title_TV);
            viewHolder.saveDownloadBtn = (Button) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_card_save_download_Btn);
            viewHolder.saveDescTV = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_card_save_desc_TV);
            viewHolder.saveAuthorTV = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_card_save_author_TV);
            viewHolder.saveUpdateTimeTV = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_card_save_update_time_TV);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(model.getSaveTitle())) {
            viewHolder.saveTitleTV.setText(model.getSaveTitle());
        } else {
            viewHolder.saveTitleTV.setText("UnKonw");
        }
        viewHolder.saveDescTV.setText("Description:\n" + model.getSaveDesc());
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(model.getSaveAuthor())) {
            viewHolder.saveAuthorTV.setText(model.getSaveAuthor());
        } else {
            viewHolder.saveAuthorTV.setText("Someone");
        }

        viewHolder.saveUpdateTimeTV.setText("Sometime");

        viewHolder.saveDownloadBtn.setText("Download ");
        viewHolder.saveDownloadBtn
                .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        showDialog("Download", "Downloading...");
                        Message msg = new Message();
                        msg.what=Constants.MSG_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE;
                        handler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, 5000);
                    }
                });

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        private ImageView gamePicIMG;
        private TextView saveTitleTV;
        private Button saveDownloadBtn;
        private TextView saveDescTV;
        private TextView saveAuthorTV;
        private TextView saveUpdateTimeTV;

    }
}
```

and i have a Handler to handler the message when download complete.

```
private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case Constants.MSG_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE:
            if(null!=dialog){
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
            //TODO 怎么更新点击的按个按钮状态为“使用”   how could i set  "Use It" to the button which i clicked. 
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

I am from China . I'm sorry for my English.Please help ,thanks.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851507/android-widget-how-to-change-the-text-of-a-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a variable to your `SaveModel` to store this state. When the download finish, change the value in the item of the list and call `notifySetDataChanged()`. In the `SaveListAdapter`, set the button text in function of this value.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Your answer is extremely useful.I fixed it.But I want to know how about i put a progressbar in each item ? How could I asyn update the progressbar , like in Google Play click "Update All".

Answer (score 0):

Keep the downloaded items positions some where in a `List` and after finishing the download functionality, call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to reload the adapter view. in this, set button title by checking the downloaded positions in the list.